# Indexing a link under an if statement?

Tags: php, seo, web-crawler, googlebot

will index Google any links witch are under an if statement?

Ex

```
     <a"; if($user_category=="register2"){ $link="href='".$databaselink; echo $link;}"> BOOK</a>
```

The links are pdf on my server.

WIll that link be seen by crawl and will be indexed?

Mention that this content is displayed without beein log in. is public. after log in user get a category wich will display the links.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find your question or code all that clear, however here's what I think you're after.

Google will take whatever the link is at the time it crawls the page.
So whatever your default link is, the crawler will take.

The crawler will not see links which require a user to login.

Comment: I have a piece of text and i want to insert in it links. I want to do that for a particular category of users. The text is public shown on page it not require log in to see it. After a user logs in the account has a category. I check that category and if it fits additional in that text will apear link. Will that links get indexed? the links are on PHP public page but it appears just for a category of log in users.

Comment: Okay, well the crawler won't pick them up as I assume the user has to login for you to identify which category they are in and whether to show the links.

Comment: It doesn't it just reads what your website gives to it. Which will be the same as your website when viewed by an unauthenticated user. The Google Bot cannot login to your website as such.

Comment: it must be something to index the links but limit acces only for the registred. has to be..

Comment: The purpose of a search engine, like Google, is to index publicly accessible web pages. If your site requires a login to view information, Google is not particularly interested in indexing it.